# NodeJS | MongoDB | How do I slow down my inserts?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have an array that is 8,000 items long and I'm creating a new document in my MongoDB Atlas database but I keep hitting the limit of 100 operations per second. I don't need the data to get in there lightning-fast (75 inserts per second is fine with me), so I tried sticking a Sleep function in the middle of the writing function, but it isn't operating as I expected.

**What I expect and want my code to do:**

1. write the first document
2. sleep for 20 milliseconds
3. write the second document

**What it seems to be doing now:**

1. write the first document
2. immediately write the second document
3. immediately write the third document

**Here's an example of the code:**

```
const Sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const MyFunction = array => {
  return Promise.all(array.map(row => {
    const item = new Item({
      "property1": row.property1,
      "property2": row.property2
    });
    Sleep(20) // tried putting a sleep here but that didn't work
    return item.save();
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await your sleep method as it is async. But even then it will not work as it will just delay the creation of promise, not the execution.

Better to use `batch-promises` https://www.npmjs.com/package/batch-promises

```
const batch = require("batch-promises");

const MyFunction = async array => {
  return batch(100, array, row => {
    const item = new Item({
      "property1": row.property1,
      "property2": row.property2
    });
    return item.save();
  });
};
```

OR if you want to do sequentially

```
const MyFunction = async array => {
  for (const row of array) {
    const item = new Item({
      "property1": row.property1,
      "property2": row.property2
    });
    await item.save();
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks again. I’ll check this solution tomorrow when I have more internet. I believe I understand now that the .map method tries to shove everything in at once whereas the sequential method you mentioned will essentially self-limit how quickly it can write.

Comment: I used your first method and limited the batch size to 90/ms and it works perfectly, thanks again!